# Direct Profile from Facebook Android

Tags: android, facebook, redirect

I want ask how can I redirect into someone's profile after successfully logging into Facebook?
Example : If successly logged in and authorized, it will direct into this page :

http://www.facebook.com/torasanshochiku.

I used [this tutorial to connect Facebook](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-facebook-sdk-android-development-part-2)

this is my **FacebookConnectionActivity** :

```
public abstract class FBConnectionActivity extends Activity {
public static final String TAG = "FACEBOOK";
private Facebook mFacebook;
public static final String APP_ID = "271496479563642";
private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
private static final String[] PERMS = new String[] { "read_stream" };
private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
private Context mContext;

private TextView username;
private ProgressBar pb;

public void setConnection() {
        mContext = this;
        mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
}

public void getID(TextView txtUserName, ProgressBar progbar) {
        username = txtUserName;
        pb = progbar;
        if (isSession()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "sessionValid");
                mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
        } else {
                // no logged in, so relogin
                Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
                mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
}

public boolean isSession() {
        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
        String access_token = sharedPrefs.getString("access_token", "x");
        Long expires = sharedPrefs.getLong("access_expires", -1);
        Log.d(TAG, access_token);

        if (access_token != null && expires != -1) {
                mFacebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
                mFacebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }
        return mFacebook.isSessionValid();
}

private class LoginDialogListener implements DialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                Log.d(TAG, "LoginONComplete");
                String token = mFacebook.getAccessToken();
                long token_expires = mFacebook.getAccessExpires();
                Log.d(TAG, "AccessToken: " + token);
                Log.d(TAG, "AccessExpires: " + token_expires);
                sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager
                                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                sharedPrefs.edit().putLong("access_expires", token_expires)
                                .commit();
                sharedPrefs.edit().putString("access_token", token).commit();
                mAsyncRunner.request("me", new IDRequestListener());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
                Log.d(TAG, "OnCancel");
        }
}

private class IDRequestListener implements RequestListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                try {
                        Log.d(TAG, "IDRequestONComplete");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                        JSONObject json = Util.parseJson(response);

                        final String id = json.getString("id");
                        final String name = json.getString("name");
                        FBConnectionActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                        username.setText("Welcome: " + name+"\n ID: "+id);
                                        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

                                }
                        });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSONException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (FacebookError e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
                        Object state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
                        Object state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                Log.d(TAG, "FacebookError: " + e.getMessage());
        }

}

//@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. You have an android activity, you can't "direct" the user to a web address inside an activity.. So, do you want to load the profile in a webview? or maybe you want to open a browser with the profile page? or maybe something else?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do to redirect a user to someone's profile is use the generic profile page link.
It looks something like this -

`//facebook.com/profile.php?id=USER_FBID`

Where `USER_FBID` is the users Facebook ID.  So all you need to do is have the users FBID and you can navigate directly to their profile with the link.  Note that I'm using a protocol relative URL to keep the user in the same protocol when redirecting.  If the user was browsing securely with `HTTPS` then they will be redirected to a secure link.  If the user is not browsing securely then they will be directed to a normal `HTTP` link.

Comment: i know to get user_fbid but how i put into code and still in facebook pop up?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.  Once you have the `user_fbid` you can redirect the user to that profile page...

Comment: my question where i should input that code..sory if make u confuse

Comment: I don't have any knowledge in Android development... But it looks to me like you know when the use is logged in when the  `LoginDialogListener >>  onComplete` function is called...  If you are not in a browser, then you can simply open the browser with the link to the users profile.